# regex to group them same name

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression, perl

I have following lines in foo.txt

```
aaa:6600 location: US

aaa:6622 location: US

xxx:6601 location: EU

xxx:6602 location: EU

xxx:6603 location: EU

ggg:7701 location: KR

ggg:8808 location: KR
```

I want to group all starting same gather and have one new line between them so final output look like following

```
    aaa:6600 location: US
    aaa:6622 location: US

    xxx:6601 location: EU
    xxx:6602 location: EU
    xxx:6603 location: EU

    ggg:7701 location: KR
    ggg:8808 location: KR
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that all lines sharing the same "start tag" (like `aaa`, `xxx`, `ggg`) are consecutive (save for the empty lines), or can they appear "scattered" anywhere within the file?

Comment: aaa, xxx, ggg could be random name sometime they are `sss111` or `r22dd` etc but they are always in group with newline (i want to group them so easy to read)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F: '/^$/{next}$1!=f&&NR>1{print ""}{f=$1;print;}' foo.txt
```

gives

```
aaa:6600 location: US
aaa:6622 location: US

xxx:6601 location: EU
xxx:6602 location: EU
xxx:6603 location: EU

ggg:7701 location: KR
ggg:8808 location: KR
```

on the sample data.

Explanation.

The `-F:` says fields are going to be delimited by colons. `/^$/{next}` says to skip all blank lines in the input. `$1!=f&&NR>1{print ""}` if the current name is not the same as the thing saved in `f` and the line number in the file is more than 1, then print a blank line to start a new group. `{f=$1;print}` for all lines save the name in `f` and print the line. There are ways to make it shorter, but for me this doesn't require anything more than basic `awk`.

Comment: awesoooooomneeeeesss!!! working great

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F':' '!NF{next} $1 != prev{if (NR>1) print ""; prev=$1} 1' file
aaa:6600 location: US
aaa:6622 location: US

xxx:6601 location: EU
xxx:6602 location: EU
xxx:6603 location: EU

ggg:7701 location: KR
ggg:8808 location: KR
```